# Finding a child in parent-child family tree

Tags: php, parent-child, multi-level

I am designing a family tree like the photo below. 
 I want to get a level of children without  calculating from the first parent.
 Is there  any algorithm or pattern for solving this problem?

[image]

http://i1337.photobucket.com/albums/o678/mnt001_129/get-family-level_zpse5c190ed.jpg

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Just to let you know that questions here are expected to contain a minimum of specific information about what you have tried, complete with any examples of code you've written as appropriate. You might get a better response to your answer if you provide more information.